# cs50p little professor question, my code get rejected because of wrong level . anyone knows why?

Tags: python, cs50

this is my code for the little professor problem , the task is when the level is not 1 ,2 or 3 repromt , this is what the code does but still get reject for the level repromt

```
:) professor.py exists
:( Little Professor rejects level of 0
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
:( Little Professor rejects level of 4
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
:( Little Professor rejects level of "one"
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
:) Little Professor accepts valid level
:) At Level 1, Little Professor generates addition problems using 0–9
:) At Level 2, Little Professor generates addition problems using 10–99
:) At Level 3, Little Professor generates addition problems using 100–999
:) Little Professor generates 10 problems before exiting
:) Little Professor displays number of problems correct
:) Little Professor displays EEE when answer is incorrect
:) Little Professor shows solution after 3 incorrect attempts
```

```
import random

def main():
    while True:
        level = get_level()
        if level.isdigit() and int(level) in [1, 2, 3]:
            break
        else:
            ...

    score = 0
    valid = False
    for i in range(10):
        tries = 3
        valid = False
        intOne = generate_integer(level)
        intTwo = generate_integer(level)
        ans = input(str(intOne) + " + " + str(intTwo) + " = ")
        while not valid:
            res = intOne + intTwo
            if int(ans) != res:
                tries -= 1
                if tries == 0:
                    valid = True
                    print(str(res))
                else:a
                    print('EEE')
                    ans = game(intOne, intTwo)
            else:
                score += 1
                valid = True
    print(score)

def get_level():
    level = input('Level: ')
    return level

def game(intOne, intTwo):
         ans = input( str(intOne) + " + "+ str(intTwo) + " = " )
         return ans

def generate_integer(level):
    if level == "2":
        return random.randint(10, 99)
    if level == "3":
        return random.randint(100, 999)
    return random.randint(0, 10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you explain what the task is (don't make me google cs50p in order to help you), what the input is, and what the expected vs actual output is? See [ask].

Comment: Where do you reject input?

Comment: Since you're not actually using `level` in any arithmetic code, you can just use `if level in ["1", "2", "3"]:` There's no need to call `isdigit()` or `int()`.

Comment: @tadman They reject the input by asking for it again in the `while` loop. That's what the instructions say it should do.

Comment: @Barmar I guess that's what the `...` part does?

Comment: Note also [mre] guidelines. A good Stack Overflow question, instead of including your _whole_ program, includes a program written _specifically_ to be the smallest/shortest thing that has the same problem as your real program when run without changes, and thus can be used to demonstrate the issue or test proposed fixes.

Comment: @tadman I don't know if `...` is literal of just a placeholder. If it's literal, it's effectively the same as `pass`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How could they shorten this? If they remove anything, the CS50 checker will find other problems.

Comment: @Barmar Fair point. I just expected to see something there that might emit a rejection notice.

Comment: The instructions simply say "If the user does not input 1, 2, or 3, the program should prompt again." Nothing about printing a rejection notice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Barmar, if they can't make the transition from a CS50 checker problem to a narrow, specific Python problem, I don't see the question as suited here in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Come on, they're a beginner and all they know is that the "instructor" said something is wrong, they can't narrow it down. As it is, I can't see the problem that it's complaining about. I ran the script myself and it correctly asked again when I entered an incorrect level.

Comment: It looks like there's a copying error: `else:a` shouldn't have `a`. It can't be the cause of the error, because it prevents the script from running at all.